# Information Regarding Schengen Visa

Tags: visas, schengen

I have a Schengen Visa issued by the Poland embassy for 20 days category C and single entry.

I have hotel reservation from 25 to 01 for this event in Poland and I have my friend in the Netherlands who can accommodate me; so I want to ask can I take my first fight to the Netherlands rather than Poland?

Comment: Welcome to Travel SE. Your question already has an answer, see the linked post and especially the third answer there!

Comment: The country whose largest city is Amsterdam is called **The Netherlands** (or, informally in English, **Holland**, though that will enrage know-it-all pedants). Not "Neither-land".

Comment: @mts: There are currently two answers to that question that tie for third place -- so if you want to point to one specific of them, it's better to say who wrote it than where in the list it is.

Comment: Is your visa only valid for Poland, or is it for the entire Schengen Zone? What does it say under "Valid For" (it is the top line on the left).

Comment: Oh, I meant the answer by @ Relaxed thanks for pointing out @HenningMakholm